# Applying texture in Xcode Scene Editor is not working

Tags: ios, scenekit, xcode9, arkit

I downloaded a 3D model(https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/industrial/machine/fuel-gas-scrubber-skid) and converted it to .dae using SketchUp.

I am not able to apply texture to this model in Xcode 9 Scene Editor. When i select any texture image(using materials->diffuse), it turns into black!!

I did the same for other models before and it was working fine. Not able to figure out what is the issue now.

I tried even changing the multiply, emission, reflective etc. properties to white color but still not able to see the texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what is wrong with the model. The model i downloaded is not UV mapped. That is why i am not able to apply the texture to it.